# ArgumentCaptor is null

Tags: junit, mockito

I'm trying to write a unit test for the code below where I instantiate a bean and pass it on to other private methods of the class for further processing before  doing what the main method does:

```
public OverviewTabViewBean build(Listing listing) {

   VehicleDetailListingBean vehicleDetailListingBean = new VehicleDetailListingBean();

   applyVehicleDetailListingRules(listing, vehicleDetailListingBean);
   OverviewTabViewBean overviewTabViewBean = new OverviewTabViewBean();

   if (vehicleDetailListingBean != null) {
        overviewTabViewBean.setMake(vehicleDetailListingBean.getMake());
        overviewTabViewBean.setModel(vehicleDetailListingBean.getModel());
      overviewTabViewBean.setAtCarId(vehicleDetailListingBean.getAtCarId());
   ..
   }

return overviewTabViewBean;
```

---

```
 private void applyCommonListingRules(Listing listing, VehicleDetailListingBean vehicleDetailListingBean) {
    rulesEngineService.applyRules(listing, vehicleDetailListingBean,   vehicleDetailRules.getCommonListingRules());
}
```

Test looks something like this:

```
@Captor
ArgumentCaptor<OverviewTabViewBean> overviewTabViewBean;
@Captor
ArgumentCaptor<VehicleDetailListingBean> vehicleDetailListingBean;
@Mock
private RulesEngineService rulesEngineService;
@Mock
private VehicleDetailRules vehicleDetailRules;
@Mock
private VehicleReferenceService vehicleReferenceService;

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

/**
 * build
 */
@Test
public void build() {
    Listing listing = new Listing();
    listing.setListingId(111L);
    listing.setListingType(ListingType.NEW);

    List<Rule<Listing, ListingBean>> rules1 = new ArrayList<Rule<Listing, ListingBean>>();
    List<Rule<Listing, ListingBean>> rules2 = new ArrayList<Rule<Listing, ListingBean>>();
    doReturn(rules1).when(vehicleDetailRules).getCommonListingRules();
    doReturn(rules2).when(vehicleDetailRules).getDetailListingRules();

    overviewTabViewBeanBuilder.build(listing);
    verify(rulesEngineService, times(2)).applyRules(anyObject(), vehicleDetailListingBean.capture(), anyList());
    .....
    }
```

**vehicleDetailListingBean** is returning as null a not stepping into the if block. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I fail to see how `vehicleDetailListingBean` can ever be `null` in the `build` method. You create a new one, then call a method (but this will not change the reference) and then check if it is not null, are you saying that if you step through it in the debugger, that `new VehicleDetailListingBean()` is `null`??